# What to do about iCloud messages to a phone I no longer have? Can I direct them to a new number?

Tags: messages

Some years ago, I had an iPhone. It was couple to my iCloud account along with my computers so that any text messages also showed up in the messaging app.

I no longer have that phone or that number. All the people who used to send me text messages to that number are still sending them, and the messages appear on my Messages app but not my new Android phone. I've told them all that I have a new number, but they're using the Messages app on their iPhones and apparently can't change (I don't think they even see the phone number they're texting to.)

This is causing all sorts of problems, since someone sends me a text message and I don't see it until I get home and turn my computer on.

Is there some way to forward these messages to my Android, or at least bounce the messages back? Is deleting my iCloud messaging completely my only recourse? Will even that work?

Answer (score 1):

You need to [Deregister iMessage on your iPhone or online](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203042).

> If you switched to a non-Apple phone and aren't getting SMS/MMS messages, you might need to deregister iMessage.

This is because iMessage can use multiple methods to message you including your phone number and email address. By deregistering, you’re telling the iMessage server you’re no longer reachable and thus should “bounce” the message sent to you.

Comment: This looks like it might work. I don't remember the phone number of my old iPhone, but maybe I can find it again. Otherwise, I may be boned.

Comment: Sigh; no joy. `error::Service Unavailable`. I gave up the phone number several years ago.